# Deploy IIB bar file in all environments without chaging the Datasource name (DNS)

Tags: database, datasource, messagebroker

We have 2 environments dev and prod. When I want to deploy a bar file created in dev to test,  I need to change the Data Source name as per the Prod. is there a way where I can not do that and be able to access the data source from somewhere without modifying my bar file.

i tried with `mqsiChnage` commands but there is no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use promoted properties. So in all your flows, promote the data source property of your compute nodes. You can change promoted properties with the command mqsiapplybaroverride or in the Toolkit, without rebuilding the BAR.

But even easier is to not use different data source names in the different environments. There is absolutely no need to use different names, as the data source names are mapped to environment specific databases in the odbc.ini, so the same data source names can point to different databases in your different environments.

Comment: i agree with you. we resolved the issue.

we used mqsichnageproperties